# Go install exclude file

Tags: go, package, installation

I have created a go script that compiles, starts, checks the status, and ends a web service I created (that is also in go). However, I have come to a road block.

With the compile feature I run the following command:

```
go install .
```

Which gives the following error:

```
./script.go:55: main redeclared in this block
previous declaration at ./hello.go:8
```

Which makes sense as I have two different files, both with the main func and main package. I also tried moving the script to another folder and then changing the command ran to:

```
go install {path}
```

Where {path} is equal to the path I want installed/compiled. Which I then got the following error:

```
exit status 1: can't load package: package /var/www/test.com/go: import "/var/www/test.com/go": cannot import absolute path
```

So in conclusion I have thought of only one solution (and I am up to hear others if mine isn't the best approach). My idea is to exclude the script file from compiling with the rest of the files, but I am unsure how to.

I did some research and couldn't find an easy way to do it (such as an --exclude flag with the go install command). Does anybody know how to accomplish what I am trying to achieve?

Thank you.

Comment: I think your attempt to separate the files into different package is the correct way. The latest error told you that `go`'s build system failed to load the specified package and it's a different error (not directly related to your original problem). Without knowing your `GOPATH` value and your project's directory structure, it is hard to suggest a solution to solve this.

Comment: As indicated by the "cannot import absolute path" error, the go tools works with import paths, not absolute paths. run `go install` with the import path.

Answer (score 0):

you could give the hello.go a different package name, that should work. Or i am missing something?

Regards
Tim

Comment: I mean I really don't want an un-needed for runetime 200 line script to be compiled as well.

Comment: what does the script? maybe this helps https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#Build_Constraints excluding a file should be possible.